# How do I split using both slashes as delimiters in awk

Tags: awk

Right now I'm trying to split a string using so:

```
echo "feature\hello-test"  | awk -F'[\\\/]' ' { print $2 }'
```

with the expectation that I'll get `hello-test`, but instead, I'm getting up empty.

The reason I'm doing it like this, is because I also need to cover the case with splitting on a forward slash (`feature/hello-test`), which does seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `awk -F'[\\\\/]' ' { print $2 }'`

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
echo "feature\hello-test
feature/hello-test"  | awk -F'[\\\\/]' ' { print $2 }'
```

Or something a bit less slashy:

```
echo "feature\hello-test
feature/hello-test"  | awk  '{split($0,arr,/[\\/]/); print arr[2]}'
```

Comment: On Windows, `echo "feature\hello-test" |  gawk.exe -F "[\\\\/]" " {print $2} " ` outputs an empty string.  It works with the beautiful `echo "feature\h\ello-test"  | c:\apps\UnixUtil\gawk.exe -F "[\\\\\\\\/]" " {print $2} "`  which prints `h` as expected.

Comment: Try: `echo "feature\hello-test" |  gawk.exe -F "\\\\|/" " {print $2} "`

Comment: `print arr[2]` could be re-written by getting the value of split(..) e.g. n = split(..) and arr[n]

Comment: @Inian: That would be for the last field rather than the second field...

Answer (score 1):

In awk strings, backslash is used to introduce [C-like escape sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Escape-Sequences) like  `\n` for newline `\b` etc. You need `\\` for representing one backslash character that needs to be treated literally and not representing an escape sequence character. So it cannot be used the same way as a forward slash `/` character.

Comment: "So it cannot be used the same way as a forward slash / character" …. this statement isn't entirely accurate - `mawk -F'/|\' '$!NF=$2'` actually works, for whacko reasons

Answer (score 0):

In both cases (`GNU Awk 5.1.0`):

```
echo "feature/hello-test"  | awk -F'[\\\\/]' '{print $2}'
echo "feature\hello-test"  | awk -F'[\\\\/]' '{print $2}'
```

With `Perl`, it's more readable:

```
echo "feature\hello-test"  | perl -F'[\\/]' -e 'print $F[1]'
```

### Output

```
hello-test
```

Comment: This doesn't cover multiple delimiters

Comment: Worked! But why do I have to use double backslashes to escape a single backslash?

Comment: Ask Alfred Aho, Peter Weinberger, and Brian Kernighan

Comment: with escape hell it would be a reallly great feature to have something like `-F {$2B $2F $3A}`  (pseudo code character values which may be separators) - or simpler yet, something like multiple separators `-F "\"  -F "/"`. Or maybe `--literal-separators -F "\/"`.    (where is the wishlist for AWK?)

Comment: If you want Perl code, it will be simpler

Comment: Added Perl way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ echo "feature\hello-test"  | awk '{sub(/^[^/\\]*[/\\]/,"",$0)}1'
hello-test
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
uno/dos/tres
uno\dos\tres
uno\dos/tres
uno/dos\tres
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{gsub(/\\/,"/");print $2}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
dos
dos
dos
dos
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is forward slash, then for each line I replace all backslashes with forward slashes using `gsub`. This causes `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` (as I have 3 columns) to be reevaluated; then I `print` 2nd field.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

ps : how is `perl` simpler than `awk` ??

> ```
> perl -F'[\\/]' -e 'print $F[1]'
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> mawk -F'/|\' '$!NF = $2'
> ```

```
hello-test
```

---

depends on which `awk` u're using :

> ```
> gawk 'BEGIN {  FS = @/\\|\//
>               OFS = "\f\r\t" } NF = NF'
> ```

---

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN {  FS = "/|\\"
>               OFS = "\f\r\t" } NF = NF'
> ```

```
feature
    hello-test
```

in fact, `mawk`s are even willing to accept this ridiculous form :

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='/|\' OFS='\f\r\t'
> ```

```
feature
    hello-test
```

Comment: -F option implicitly sets -n and -a. Thus, you could write `perl -F'[\\/]' -e 'print $F[1]'`

Comment: @Supertech : i dunno `perl` at all i was just copy-pasting what others wrote, at the time of that writing. i'll go update mine now, but it's still more complex than `awk` afterwards